# What does rc mean in angular versions

Tags: angularjs, version, abbreviation

There are a lot of angular versions here. beta means still incomplete and not to use for production.

but what is the meaning of rc.
https://code.angularjs.org/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

rc is release candidate. This means no new feature will be introduced just a bugfix releases before final release.

Comment: Well, that's what it's *supposed* to mean, but the Angular 2 team certainly doesn't seem to use it that way, since between release candidates they've deprecated and replaced the router, and added the new NgModule functionality.

Comment: @IanMcLaird Finally angular 2 team admitted it that they broke lot of stuff during rc. So now they will use [semver](http://semver.org) to avoid confusion, and breaking changes will be once in 6 months.